# Bad practice having 2 locks in same method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I am wondering if this is a bad code design to have 2 separate locks used in the same method. I believe the reason the two locks were first implemented was the fields they were updating were unrelated.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly object _lock = new object();
  private readonly object _lock2 = new object();

  public async Task DoStuff()
  {
    lock(_lock)
    {
      //do some stuff
    }
    lock(_lock2)
    {
      //do some other stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say the `_lock` is used to only modify an `int` variable and `_lock2` is used to modify and `List<string>` variable. Both locks can be called from other methods in the class on different threads. Is there a smell for a deadlock here? It seems like I should refactor this so the `DoStuff` method should only utilize one lock type.

Comment: You shouldn't be locking in an `async` method in the first place, unless there are no awaits within the body of either `lock`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's okay for the two blocks of code to be running concurrently from different invocations, then there is no problem with having two objects to `lock` on.  If it's *important* that the two blocks be able to run at the same time then it's essential that you *do* have different objects to `lock` on.  If it's important the two blocks not actually run at the same time, and that the entire operation be treated as one logically atomic operation, then you should use one `lock`.

The two options have entirely different semantics, neither is inherently wrong or inherently right.  You need to use the right one for the situation that you're in.

Answer (score 0):

That code is dead lock safe. There is no situation in this code when lock would prevent thread that is already in critical section from leaving it. Therefore this thread will always release obtained lock for another thread